# Collection of mathematics and scientific papers of the "greats"

Tags: research

Is there any resource that has a great deal of the papers of the greats of mathematics and science(mainly interested in physics).

Einstein, Noether, Gauss, Euler, Newton, Galios, etc and all the millions of the rest.

I'm talking about pivotal papers/articles that were significant to areas of math and/or science. Usually these are the ones that are referred to by some other great or used as a foundation for their own research.

Ideally it would be free and a downloadable collection sorted by name and area or searchable/tagged.

Comment: There are simply too many.  The works of Ramanjan alone are still being edited, and he died a century ago.  "Millions of the rest...."  Hah!

Comment: @DavidG.Stork too many? Is something better than nothing? You seem to think not. If the paper exist it either has to be printed or in digital form... if it it is popular it has to exist somewhere and at some point will become digital form. It does not take much to scan in a document. Millions of books have been scanned, each book being at least 10x most papers.

Comment: These papers exist, but not "sorted by name and area... tagged" as a group.  Go to scholar.google.com and search.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork The problem with searching is that it can take some time to find the actual research papers. I also don't know ever paper. I'd like to just read through them rather than hunt them down. I would expect research institutes to have such collections unified in some way for their fellows. After all, most journals published books in the past with all the papers of that subject precisely for these reasons...  I can download all the episodes of Star Trek or the Big bang theory easily but I can't download some of the most important documents of humanity easily?